# What functions should I add for a numpy array to take into account whether another numpy array contains a single element or multiple elements?

Tags: python

I have the following code below

```
 populations = numpy.array([[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(len(q_active))] for y in range(4)])
```

I was wondering, what should I add to the code above so it could take into account if the `q_active` has one or more elements inside

As of now, when I run the code I get this error:

```
populations = numpy.array([[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(len(q_active))] for y in range(4)])
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: What is `type(q_active)`?

Comment: @Mario Ishac numpy.ndarray

Comment: your goal is to make an array of shape (4, len(q_active))?

Comment: If it does, i think there is a neater way to achieve this, either way, try changing `len(q_active)` to `q_active.size`

Comment: also, I cannot reproduce your bug. I.e. the following code runs well for me. If you work with jupyter notebook (or any other python notebook) try to recheck if you ran the cell containing q_active or if you defined it as an `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: @A.Maman my goal is that whether there is only one element or multiple elements inside `q_active ` there should be no problem executing it. Right now, my code accepts multiple elements inside of `q_active` but when there is only a single element it produces errors

Comment: Hi, I mean what is the expected outcome of the code? is it a random array of size 4 X len(q_active)?

Comment: yes, so for `q_active = [8] ` then `populations ` should give something like: `populations = [[1] [0] [1] [1]] ` another example outcome is if  `q_active = [2 3] ` then `populations ` should produce something like: `populations = [[1 0] [1 1] [0 0] [1 0]] `

Comment: Also note that 1 and 0 is randomized @A.Maman

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the following code does not produce the desired outcome, since when I run:

```
import numpy as np
import random

q_active = [8]

populations = np.array([[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(len(q_active))] for y in range(4)])

print(populations)
```

outputs:

```
[[1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]]
```

- where the 0's and 1's are random

But if it still doesn't work for you, try alternative way:

```
import numpy as np

q_active = [8]

populations = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(4, len(q_active)))

print(populations)
```

outputs:

```
[[1]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]]
```

- where the 0's and 1's are random

If still does not work, try also:

```
populations = np.random.randint(0, 2, (4, q_active.shape[0]))
```